# SQL Select where the date is min and max

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to  SQL queries and I need to make a join starting from this query:

```
SELECT b.Name AS VehicleName,
       a.*
FROM   VehicleDay AS a
       INNER JOIN
       Vehicles AS b
       ON a.VehicleId = b.Id
WHERE  b.SiteId = 100
       AND a.Day >= '2016-04-22'
       AND a.Day < '2016-04-28';
```

and adding 6 more columns from the Info data table:

Starting (first value of the day) & Ending (last of day)
-          Cumulative [Cml]
-          Current Capacity [Cap]
-          Total charge [Chrg]

So I need to add on at the far right
 S Cml  |  E Cml |  S Cap  |  E Cap  |  S Chrg |  E Chrg

In the Info table I get values for the same VehicleId on different period of day and I need to select the first and the last data for each day in a daterange.

So far my query looks like this:

```
SELECT b.Name AS VehicleName,
       a.*,
       c.MaxDay,
       c.Cumulative,
       c.CurrentCapacity,
       c.TotalCharge
FROM   VehicleDay AS a
       INNER JOIN
       Vehicles AS b
       ON a.VehicleId = b.Id
       INNER JOIN
       (SELECT   VehicleId,
                 MAX(TimestampLocal) AS MaxDay,
                 CAST (TimestampLocal AS DATE) AS Day,
                 Cumulative,
                 CurrentCapacity,
                 TotalCharge
        FROM     Info
        GROUP BY VehicleId, 
                 CAST (TimestampLocal AS DATE), 
                     Cumulative, CurrentCapacity, TotalCharge) AS c
       ON a.VehicleId = c.VehicleId
          AND a.Day = c.Day
WHERE  b.SiteId = 100
       AND a.Day >= '2016-04-22'
       AND a.Day < '2016-04-28';
```

But the second query returns more rows that the first one and I need to display the number of rows as the first one.

Is there a way I can add those 6 columns into my query without adding more rows?

Comment: Is the data in the columns coming from the `VehicleDay` and `Vehicles` tables duplicated in other rows by any chance?

Comment: No. The Vehicles table contains only the Id and the Name and that Id is a foreign key to VehicleDay, that contains informations that are loaded each day

Comment: I mean in the "additional rows" you mention seeing with the second query. Put another way, are there any pairs of rows that have matching values for their `VehicleId` and `Day` entries?

Comment: So you want the earliest and the latest `TimestampLocal` for a given vehicle and date? That would come from two records in `Info`, and each would have its proper values for `Cumulative`, `CurrentCapacity` and so. Which of these values will you want to have in your results?

Comment: @trincot Yes, that's they way I want to get the values. I want the values for all columns: Cumulate, currentCapacity and so on, displayed in different columns for the earliest and for the latest.  I will give you an example: for today I got 3 rows - one at 9:00, the second at 14:15 and the last at 18:02, each row containing different values for Cumulative, CurrentCapacity and so. I need a way to retrieve the first and the third row (with the smallest time and with the biggest time) for today

Comment: @Invictus Yes, there were. It's because of my group by clause, I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the duplicates is that you group also by `Cumulative, CurrentCapacity, TotalCharge`, which may have different values on the same day. So then that `GROUP BY` will serve multiple records per day and so multiply the records already selected from the two other tables.

You could first just get the MIN/MAX values of the time stamps, and then with these values, join the table `Info` twice again, once to retrieve the columns related to the MIN time, and once for those related to the MAX time:

```
SELECT      b.Name AS VehicleName,
            a.*,
            c.S_Time,
            c.E_Time,
            s.Cumulative      AS S_Cml,
            e.Cumulative      AS E_Cml,
            s.CurrentCapacity AS S_Cap,
            e.CurrentCapacity AS E_Cap,
            s.TotalCharge     AS S_Chrg,
            e.TotalCharge     AS E_Chrg
FROM        VehicleDay AS a
INNER JOIN  Vehicles AS b
        ON  a.VehicleId = b.Id
LEFT JOIN   (SELECT  VehicleId,
                     CAST (TimestampLocal AS DATE) AS Day,
                     MIN(TimestampLocal) AS S_Time,
                     MAX(TimestampLocal) AS E_Time
            FROM     Info
            GROUP BY VehicleId,
                     CAST (TimestampLocal AS DATE)
            ) AS c
        ON  a.VehicleId = c.VehicleId
        AND a.Day = c.Day
LEFT JOIN   Info AS s
        ON  s.VehicleId = c.VehicleId
        AND s.TimestampLocal = c.S_Time
LEFT JOIN   Info AS e
        ON  e.VehicleId = c.VehicleId
        AND e.TimestampLocal = c.E_Time
WHERE       b.SiteId = 100
        AND a.Day >= '2016-04-22'
        AND a.Day < '2016-04-28'
```

There is one condition: the combination `VehicleId` and `TimestampLocal` must be unique, or you'll still get more rows than expected.